# Do iMacros support a right-click through mouse?

Tags: java, .net

I was trying to record an iMacro for a task wherein I had to record a webpage login, alongwith a user and password, and after logging ino it, I had to right-click the webpage and select 'Saveframe as', where the entire frame should be saved to some specific location. When I tried this and tried to play, I am unable to view the right-click and 'Save frame as'. Please suggest if right-click (by mouse) is possible in iMacro.
The operating system on my workstation is 'Windows 7'.
The iMacro is being recorded and played on 'Mozilla Firefox 23.0.1' (As I need it over Mozilla Firefox and no other browser).
The iMacro version that I am using is the add-on 'iMacro 8.8.1'.

I will not be able to paste the code here, as it is confidential.

Kindly assist me for the above problem as soon as possible.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Jack.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a tag command to extract HTM code from that FRAME. Check the HTML property of that code and make a TAG command. http://wiki.imacros.net/TAG

Then use SAVEAS command to save the code to a file. http://wiki.imacros.net/SAVEAS